# PERL with Win32:ODBC/DBI reads many tables fine, then one returns nothing

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc

```
##Read table staStations
if ($mssqldb->Sql("SELECT stationID, security, dockingCostPerVolume, maxShipVolumeDockable, officeRentalCost, operationID, stationTypeID, corporationID, solarSystemID, constellationID, regionID, stationName, reprocessingEfficiency, reprocessingStationsTake, reprocessingHangarFlag
 FROM staStations")) {
    print "SQL Error: " . $mssqldb->Error() . "\n";
    $mssqldb->disconnect;
    exit;
}


# Read table staStations
$count = 0 ;

while ($mssqldb->FetchRow) {
    my ($stationID, $security, $dockingCostPerVolume, $maxShipVolumeDockable, $officeRentalCost, $operationID, $stationTypeID, $corporationID, $solarSystemID, $constellationID, $regionID, $stationName, $reprocessingEfficiency, $reprocessingStationsTake, $reprocessingHangarFlag) = $mssqldb->Data();  ### Get data values from the row
    $stationName =~ s/\'/\&apos;/g;
    $mysqlconnect->do("INSERT INTO staStations(stationID, security, dockingCostPerVolume, maxShipVolumeDockable, officeRentalCost, operationID, stationTypeID, corporationID, solarSystemID, constellationID, regionID, stationName, reprocessingEfficiency, reprocessingStationsTake, reprocessingHangarFlag)
    VALUES ('$stationID', '$security', '$dockingCostPerVolume', '$maxShipVolumeDockable', '$officeRentalCost', '$operationID', '$stationTypeID', '$corporationID', '$solarSystemID', '$constellationID', '$regionID', '$stationName', '$reprocessingEfficiency', '$reprocessingStationsTake', '$reprocessingHangarFlag') ;");
    $count = $count + 1 ;
    print $count . " Rows into staStations \n" ;

}
```

that 1st part works fine

```
    if ($mssqldb->Sql("SELECT iconID, iconFile, description FROM eveIcons")) {
    print "SQL Error: " . $mssqldb->Error() . "\n";
    $mssqldb->disconnect;
    exit;
}



# write table eveIcons
foreach ($mssqldb->FetchRow()) {
    my ($iconID, $iconFile, $description) = $mssqldb->Data();  ### Get data values from the row
    $description =~ s/\'/\&apos;/g;
    #$iconFile  =~ s/\_/\&#95;/g;
    print "iconID: " . $iconID . "\n" ;
    print "file: " . $iconFile . "\n" ;
    print "desc: " . $description . "\n \n" ;
    $mysqlconnect->do("INSERT INTO eveIcons(`iconID`, `iconFile`, `description`)
    VALUES ('$iconID', '$iconFile', '$description') ;");
    $count = $count + 1 ;
    print $count . " Rows into eveIcons \n" ;
}
```

can't find a problem, but nothing is returned
this reads no data..

it places a "0" in the first column of my MySql table

there is 1689 records in the MSSQL table,  what am i doing worng??

Answer (score 1):

I've had troubles with reading long data columns from mssql and LongTruncOk and LongReadLen solved them.

It seems you are having trouble writing them. Try and have a look at this artice: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sample.doc%2Fdoc%2Fperl%2Fs-dtlob-pl.htm

There are samples of how to write a blob. Try to apply that to your description field.

Answer (score 0):

i don't quite understand why, but something about the description field on the MSSQL server
was attempting to allocate alot of memory, once i stoped trying to copy that column, it worked fine,

more info
datatype on the MSSQL table is set to VARCHAR(MAX),
though none of the fields in that column had more that 127 characters